# ошибка при инсталляции пакета tinvest

Tags: python, pip

Первый раз работаю с питоном (версия 3.10), поэтому возможно ошибки элементарные. Устанавливаю пакет tinvest (https://github.com/daxartio/tinvest) практически на все функции выдаётся похожая ошибка

```
Using cached aiohttp-3.6.3.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7oyeka32'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hoi1ujb4\aiohttp_a2954fad851d4a7e9e9f31249cf2a712
    Complete output (25 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-f2rf2gi5\aiohttp.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/6c/429faa2d2f73973189ca0cfe141ff703417a5eebe18d78e6b25b70db0a34/aiohttp-3.6.3.tar.gz#sha256=698cd7bc3c7d1b82bb728bae835724a486a8c376647aec336aa21a60113c3645 (from https://pypi.org/simple/aiohttp/) (requires-python:>=3.5.3). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7oyeka32' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Здесь и проблема с кодировкой и ошибка метаданных. Это решается настройками?
Хотелось бы услышать пояснение и где можно посмотреть, что с этим делать.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не устанавливайте Python в папку с кириллическими символами.

Изменните имя пользователя, Windows должен переименовать папку:

```
C:\Users\Ирина\
```

на

```
C:\Users\Iren\
```

Потом должно заработать.

---

Не верен, что переиминует автоматом, поэтому поищите гайд, как переименовать папку, или переустановите Python.